# can AWS athena partition or columns be created from S3 bucket sub-directories?

Tags: amazon-athena

Our s3 buckets generally have a number of sub-directories, so that the path to a bucket is something like s3:functional-group/service/org-tenant-company-id/entity-id/actual-data

We're looking into Athena to be able to query against data on that /actual-data level, but within the org-tenant-company-id. So it seems like we need a way to either create a column or partition for that org-tenant-company-id. Is this possible?

I've read the page on partitions in the Athena docs. Seems like we may have to manually create partitions via the JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can manually create the partitions, but if you set up you folder structure in hive format for example (s3:functional-group/service/org-tenant-company-id=xxxx/), the you can simply do a "MSCK REPAIR TABLE" command and Athena will automatically create all partitions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the path as an attribute ([How to get input file name as column in AWS Athena external tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011433/how-to-get-input-file-name-as-column-in-aws-athena-external-tables)) and use CTAS to create partitions.